# flutter: invalid radix-10 number while using acceleromter

Tags: flutter, dart, save, accelerometer

at the sizeaccelerometer2.numberx = int.parse(accelerometer[0]); line an error occures:

I/flutter ( 9802): Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)

I don't really know what to do. I think there is converting the accelerometer[0] to an integer but I don't really know why there is an issue.

```
final List<String> accelerometer =
_accelerometerValues?.map((double v) => v.toStringAsFixed(1))?.toList();
final List<String> gyroscope =
_gyroscopeValues?.map((double v) => v.toStringAsFixed(1))?.toList();
final List<String> userAccelerometer = _userAccelerometerValues
    ?.map((double v) => v.toStringAsFixed(1))
    ?.toList();

var sizeaccelerometer2 = values();
sleep(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
sizeaccelerometer2.numberx = int.parse(accelerometer[0]);
sizeaccelerometer2.numbery = accelerometer[1];
sizeaccelerometer2.numberz = accelerometer[2];
sizeaccelerometer2.velocityx = sizeaccelerometer2.numberx + 
sizeaccelerometer2.velocityx;
sizeaccelerometer2.velocityy;
```

I'd like to be able to receive the number value to calculate velocity from acceleration

Comment: should I add more code to make my question make sense?

Answer (score 0):

so from EvenAccelerometer type to string.

This is done with .String()

Then it has to be converted to double with double.parse()

it is important to convert to double and not int